# How to solve entity framework core System.ArgumentNullException

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

From the following stacktrace, I can't tell what is wrong by the error message. I ran the migration command with `--verbose` flag hoping it would help pinpoint the issue but zilch.

```
  dotnet ef migrations add migwl3 --verbose
```

I can't find a parameter named `key`

```
  System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
  Parameter name: key
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T   value, String parameterName)
   at     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerMetadataExtensions.SqlServer(IKey key)
   at    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.    <Add>d__41.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__35`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.   <Add>d__29.MoveNext()
   at     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.   <DiffCollection>d__56`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.S      ort(IEnumerable`1 operations, DiffContext diffContext)
  at      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.Scaf      foldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String      subNamespace)
   at     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMig      ration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
  at      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(S    tring name, String outputDir, String contextType)
  at     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
  at     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Exec     ute(Action action)
 Value cannot be null.
 Parameter name: key
```

Any tips on how to zero in on the issue (the project compiles fine) would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the first results from searching for `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotNull`, so I'll add my stupid mistake:

I refactored a class to a different DatabaseContext, and was then calling `Join` between two `IQueryable` queries from those different contexts-- Obviously you can't do that in EntityFramework

Answer (score 2):

I think Your Problem is Your Model that you not decoration `[Key]` attribute Or 
Not use `HasKey`.
please share your code.

Comment: Thanks! @Soheil It was a Cluster F! issue with the tables and the models - it would be nice if ef errors were more useful :-)

Comment: @willlopez please add your codes in your ask that you get better answer

Comment: Typically I would @Soheil_Alizadeh but in this case I didn't know where to start and there are too many models and dbcontext to post :-). Thanks again for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you wrote the Interface name in the constructor not the repository name.

example program

```
private IReviewRepository _reviewRepository;
private IPokemonRepository _pokemonRepository;
private readonly IReviewerRepository _reviewerRepository;
private IMapper _mapper;

public ReviewController(IReviewRepository reviewRepository, 
    IMapper mapper, 
    IPokemonRepository pokemonRepository,
    IReviewerRepository reviewerRepository)
{
    _reviewRepository = reviewRepository;
    _pokemonRepository = pokemonRepository;
    _reviewerRepository = reviewerRepository;
    _mapper = mapper;
}
```

**ReviewRepository** instead of **IReviewRepository**

**ReviewerRepository** instead of **IReviewerRepository**

**PokemonRepository** instead of **IPokemonRepository**