# .Net Entity Framework Core Joining Multiple DB Contexts

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I am trying to execute the below query

```
 from st in _context.tbl_A
 join ex in _context.tbl_B on st.ApplicantId equals ex.ApplicantId     
 join de in _contextCNS.tbl_C on st.DegreeId equals de.ID
 where st.ApplicantId == AppId
```

On Executing the query I am getting ERRROR -------

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: entityType
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerMetadataExtensions.SqlServer(IEntityType entityType)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't post all your project here. Make small and simple sample that shows your problem only. It is really hard to read.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54659045/3408531

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to inner join tables from different Data Context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537805/how-to-inner-join-tables-from-different-data-context)

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you are joining on a nullable columns please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341858/linq-join-query-with-nullable-ref-between-table) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28936434/linq-left-join-on-nullableint)
Or other sources addressing "joining on a nullable"

Basically

you should specify a default value for the nullable

Or

Ignore the records having a value of null inside the where clause